# jQuery validation for nullable data type

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I am not sure why the jquery validation fires when the property is nullable `int?`and not marked with any data annotation attribute. Its asp.net MVC 4 application

```
public class MyViewModel{

   public int? ResourceId { get; set; }

}
```

MyView.cshtml

```
@model MyViewModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ResourceId, 
     ((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["resourceLookup"]),"--Select--")
```

Generated HTML

```
<select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ResourceId must be a number." 
           id="ResourceId" name="ResourceId">
  <option value="">--Select--</option>
  <option value="1">Type 1</option>
</select>
```

This select box is an optional one. User may ignore it. But when they ignore i am getting error message `The field ResourceId must be a number.`

In Global.asax.cs, I tried setting AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes property to prevent adding the data-* attributes to unwanted fields. But as the name says it prevents only adding data-required-* attributes.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
 DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes=false;
}
```

**How can I prevent the data type checking attribute(data-val-number) here?**

**EDIT:**

Tried setting DataType also no use, still having same issue. It looks like this will not be applied for `<select>` and may be applied only for `<input>` and set `type="text"`

```
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public int? ResourceId { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and just switched off client-side validation for my dropdown list.
You can deactivate validation for this field by setting data-val = "false":

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ResourceId, 
 ((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["resourceLookup"]),"--Select--", new { @data_val = "false" })
```

This will not remove the data-val-number attribute but prevent the validation.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the `ViewData["resourceLookup"]` try adding `-1` for the option `Select`.

Thanks!

Comment: No. I am expecting either null or a valid number. The stored procedures were created to handle NULL/valid id and many JOINS are based on that. I do not want to make changes through out the system for this simple validation.

Comment: Can you please mention what is the jQuery and jQuery validation version ?

Comment: It got nothing to do with jQuery & valiation versions. Its about preventing the asp.net mvc validation attribute that generates data-val-number attribute for int? It should accept empty string or the integer values. As of now, it is not accepting empty string.

Comment: You have mentioned that you are getting validation error message when you are not setting the select box value. I tried with sample application and it is not giving the validation error to me for int? field. I would like to test with your versions.

Comment: Check with `<option value="">--select--</option>`.. Can you paste the html generated for your sample dropdown here?

Comment: `<select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ResourceId must be a number." id="ResourceId" name="ResourceId" class="valid"> <option value="">--Select--</option>` It has `class="valid"`.

Comment: jQuery Validation Plugin - v1.11.0, jQuery 2.0.3. Can you make a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ here?

Comment: I also had issues when I just update the jQuery and validation plugin to same versions you have, but I was able to solve the issue after updating the jQuery.Validation.Unobtrusive. Try `Install-Package Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation`.